# A particular generalization of free partially commutative monoids

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids, formal-languages, automata-theory

A trace monoid, or free partially commutative monoid, is one with the presentation $\langle \Sigma \mid a_1b_1 = b_1a_1, \dots, a_nb_n = b_na_n\rangle$. The theory of trace monoids has been [well studied](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Book-of-Traces-Diekert-Rozenberg/057d8cc1e804a03f3f8f622975a02b9b2d5da1bd) since the 60s, notably among computer scientists for its applications to concurrent analysis. As far as I (and my supervisor, who introduced this idea) know, there is no mention in the literature of a reasonable generalization of trace monoids allowing select pairs of words over $\Sigma$ to commute, not only pairs of characters. Has this sort of monoid ever been studied: in particular, its computability-theoretical aspects?

Edit: as @Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda pointed out in the comments, the most immediate problems, such as the word problem, will be obviously decidable. I am instead looking for research on when certain problems will be *regular*, or requiring constant space complexity; slightly weaker properties such as context-free are also relevant. For instance: one natural question to ask is whether a particular trace monoid evaluates two word representations to be the same.

In the realm of trace monoids, checking whether $\dot{a_1}u\dot{a_2}$ is equivalent to an element of the form $v\dot{a_2}v'\dot{a_1}v''$, i.e. "Can the distinguished characters $\dot{a_1}$ and $\dot{a_2}$ be swapped?" is decidable by a finite automaton for a fixed trace monoid. For the generalized case, regularity fails in the simplest of cases (e.g., $aab = aba$).

Comment: Well, at least you’ll know that all sorts of problems will be obviously decidable for all such monoids (word problem, membership problems, etc.). Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by its “computability-theoretic aspects”?

Comment: Good point. I've revised the question accordingly.